# how to use the type of compile time constant primitive

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, primitive

How to use the type of a compile time constant primitive as type declaration for other variables?

I am trying to do some template metaprogramming in c++ for SI unit conversion. It comes down to how to automatically determine which primitive precision I need after one plus operator. For example:

```
template<typename Precision>
class Unit {
public:
    Unit(Precision v) : value(v) {}
    Precision value;
};
template<typename Precision1, typename Precision2>
struct PrecisionTransform {
    constexpr static auto test = (Precision1)1 * (Precision2)1; // Compile time constant
    using Type = Precision1; // TODO: ideally typeof(test)
};
template<typename Precision1, typename Precision2>
Unit<PrecisionTransform<Precision1, Precision2>::Type> operator+(const Unit<Precision1>& x, const Unit<Precision2>& y)
{
    return Unit<PrecisionTransform<Precision1, Precision2>::Type>(x.value + y.value);
}

int main()
{
    Unit<double> a = 2.0;
    Unit<float> b = 1.0f;
    auto c = a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

or in simple terms, can some thing like this happen?

```
float a = 1;
typeof(a) b = 2;
```

It seems quite possible since I've gone this far. But I am not sure how to use

Comment: are you looking for `decltype()`?

Comment: I think you are right, but how can I avoid using that ugly `(Precision1)1*(Precision2)1`test?

Comment: But you're interested in that value or only in the type of `test`? If you're only interested in the type, I suppose you can use `std::common_type` or, maybe better, `decltype( std::declval<Precision1>() * std::declval<Precision2>())`

Comment: This is great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. As max66 already pointed out, use `decltype`. First of all, you can replace your `PrecisionTransform` class with the follwing type alias (you have to `#include <utility>` for this):

```
template <typename Precision1, typename Precision2>
using TransformType = decltype(std::declval<Precision1>() * std::declval<Precision2>());
```

The `std::declval<XYZ>()` is just a more generic way of saying `(Precision1)1` which allows you to also use types that don't have accessible constructors (in your case irrelevant as you only use primitives).

Your `operator+` is then changed to:

```
template<typename Precision1, typename Precision2>
Unit<TransformType<Precision1, Precision2>> operator+(const Unit<Precision1>& x, const Unit<Precision2>& y)
{
    return Unit<TransformType<Precision1, Precision2>>(x.value + y.value);
}
```

Note that you got a typo in your version of `operator+` (both operands used `Precision1`).

As you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Rjtc3A), the major compilers agree on this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Everyday I find new cool things about C++. And thanks for godblot, I previously didn’t know about this website

Comment: And in your answer `decltype<XYZ>()`, you mean `declval<XYZ>()`, right?